# Cart transform function

Tags: shopify-app, shopify-api

I want to create an expanded bundle using the cart transform. First, I copied 'input.grqphql' and 'index.ts' like this: [PR (https://github.com/Shopify/function-examples/pull/276)]

After that, I deployed the cart transform function and obtained the ID. [cart transform id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xjps.png)
Then, I created a cart transform object using GraphQL and received this object.

Following that, I created a product variant and configured 2 metafields accordingly

However, it is not working on the checkout page.
Did I miss something or misunderstand?

Expand bundle in checkout page